# How to wrap multiple blocks

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-5.6

I need to wrap a custom number of blocks on a page to apply a grid system to them.

I know about `setBlockWrapperStart()` and `setBlockWrapperEnd()`, but these are applied after each block that is generated.

Let's say I have 12 Blocks of a given type and I want to wrap the first one at the beginning with `<div class="row">` and after the 4th one I want to append `</div>`. And with next (5th block) I want to start with `<div class="row">` again...

Is there any way to implement that with concrete 5? I use the standard output right now and couldn't figure out how to add a loop or something to it to implement my approach:

```
$b = new Area('Test Block');
$b->display($c);
```

I'm using concrete 5.6.3.4. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing an override.

For this I copied the `area.php` from `concrete/models/` to `models/area.php`and inserted the `function display(&$c, $alternateBlockArray) {...}` from `concrete/core/models/area.php` and adjusted it to my needs. With this I'm save for future CMS updates and can adjust the function without accidentally "destroying" the core functionality. :)

If you have any questions regarding this, feel free to ask me!

Comment: That's a good idea but how do you deal with different situations? Say when you don't want the wrapper? Did you set a variable or something?

Comment: Yes, I check if the blocktype handle is the one I need. It's easy to filter according to your needs, all the info you need are in the $c and $b objects..

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to use a quick and dirty hack and add HTML blocks with your markup in them in between your other blocks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer a cleaner approach and luckily I found one! :) see my answer..